# enemy isn't apearing pygame

Tags: python, pygame

```py
import random 
import pygame 
import time 
import os 
import keyboard

pygame.init() 
pygame.font.init() 
pygame.mixer.init() 

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))
shot = pygame.mixer.Sound(os.path.join('sgb12c.mp3')) 
pygame.display.set_caption('Space Invaders') 
icons = pygame.image.load("uno.png") 
pygame.display.set_icon(icons) 
player_image = pygame.image.load("spaceship.png") 
running = True 
shot_1_img = pygame.image.load("shott.png") 
enemy1_img = pygame.image.load("f_zombie.png") 
enemy2_img = pygame.image.load("s_zombie.png") 
enemy3_img = pygame.image.load("t_zombie.png") 
enemys = (enemy2_img, enemy2_img, enemy3_img)

places_enms = [300, 150, 400, 450, 350, 550, 500, 600, 650, 700] 
places_enm = random.choice(places_enms)

place_en = [150, 100, 50, 200, 250] 
place_ens = random.choice(place_en)
pri = random.choice(enemys) 
def enemy():
    screen.blit(pri, (places_enm, place_ens))

    def player(x, y):
        screen.blit(player_image, (x, y))
    
        shooting = True
    
        shot.set_volume(0.9) 

        player_image_pos_w = int(pygame.Surface.get_width(player_image)) 
        player_image_pos_h = int(pygame.Surface.get_height(player_image)) 
        while running is True:
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                mouse_ps = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
                x_m, y_m = mouse_ps
                screen.fill((0, 204, 204))
                u_x = x_m - 20
                u_y = 400
    
                # noinspection PyArgumentList
                player(u_x, u_y)
                enemy()
                if keyboard.is_pressed('w'):
                
                    pygame.mixer.Sound.play(shot)
                
                    screen.blit(shot_1_img, (u_x, u_y))
    
                    u_y += 1
    
                    time.sleep(0.20)
                    print('bahjat')

            pygame.display.update()
```

My enemy isn't apearing on my screen.

Comment: Please format your code as code, not as quote. You'll get better answers if people can copy & paste your code to try it.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22186

Comment: Try changing `enemy` to be hard-coded values rather than picking random image/location. If it works then, the problem is setting up the random values. If it doesn't work, then there is a problem in the game loop logic. The messed up formatting makes it impossible to decipher the game loop logic to see if there is an obvious problem.

Answer (score 0):

With the correct indentation, we can see the error: you update the player in the `event` `for` loop:

```py
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        ...
        player(...)
```

1. Indent your game loop like that:

```py
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        pass # only get the events here

    # outside of the for loop, update the player
    screen.fill((0, 204, 204))

    player(pygame.mouse.get_pos()[0] - 20, 400)
    enemy()

    pygame.display.update()
```

Otherwise, if no event is detected, the player does not appear.

2. You must also get the `pygame.QUIT` event in order to detect when the user closes the window, for example like that:

```py
while running:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT: # if the user clicks on the X, close PyGame
            pygame.quit()
                exit()

    # next code here
```

---

More information about `pygame.event` can be found in the [documentation](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html).